# Bandwidth for video streaming estimate

Tags: video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, bandwidth

A buddy and I are developing a streaming video service that functions like a TV channel for showing pre-recorded videos LIVE 24/7 on a schedule. However, we have no idea how much bandwidth something like this would consume.

How much bandwidth per month would we consume if we have 250 concurrent viewers watching 1080p streams for 1 hour each?

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but I'm not sure how you intend on building a streaming service if you don't understand the concepts of bitrate and simple multiplication.

Comment: I'm not the only developer on the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have something that weighs X, and I put 250 things in a box every second for 1 hour how much does the box weigh. But you don't say what X is. So, is your question "what are reasonable values for X"? Assuming h.264, blue ray quality, X is something like 20000000 mbit/s. Netflix HD is about 5000000 mbit/s. Twitch quality is about 3500000. I will leave the multiplication to you.

Comment: Okay thank you, but where are you getting the numbers from for Netflix and Twitch?

Comment: It my job to know them. If you wish to confirm, just play a stream, and look at the bandwidth meter in your OS.